# Passing variable in xml with hard coded entries

Tags: xml, powershell

I am using Powershell Scripts to input values into a XML file. The output file will be an XML file with all the entries entered by the user within it's diffrent fields. A part of the XML file has to hard coded just go get the required output, and now i am facing problem as i have to pass a few variables through those hard coded entries. would appreciate suggestion.
Thank You :)

```
$Variable_value_fetched_through_other_function = $Variable


$global:xmlWriter.WriteRaw('<artefact scope="machine">$Variable</artefact>')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use double quotes and escape the quotes within the string e. g.

```
$global:xmlWriter.WriteRaw("<artefact scope=`"machine`">$Variable</artefact>")
```

or you could use a format string:

```
$global:xmlWriter.WriteRaw('<artefact scope="machine">{0}</artefact>' -f $Variable)
```